# Making Python scripts run on Windows without specifying ".py" extension

Tags: python, windows, windows-7

I want to able to open a command prompt at the folder which contains a python script and just type in the script name without the .py and watch it run.

Following the various tips on google to do this, I do:

1. Add the python.exe to my path
2. Add .py to PATHEXT
3. Try to open the .py file in windows explored.  When prompted with: What program do you want to open this? I navigate to my python.exe

What should happen is the python.exe should be added to the 'Open With' pop up, but it is not? I re try with the python.exe off my path.  Same problem.

Note every time I set a path it is in the control panel. Version of python is 2.7.  And to make things stranger, I can associate .py programs with pythonw - but this is no use, as I want the console.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is happening behind the scenes when this is done? One should be able to do this from *Powershell* command line...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add .PY to PATHEXT as noted before

Then do:

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File=c:\Python27\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Adding python to the path isn't necessary to execute the script in a command prompt or double clicking in Explorer, only if you want to start an interactive python session or running the script with `python yourscript.py`

See http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html for more details.

Comment: If you have more than one version of Python installed (like 2.7.x and 3.4), you might want to use `ftype Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`.

Answer (score 14):

Modify the `PATHEXT` variable to include Python scripts. For example, here's mine:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY
```

You can do this every time you open a command console, or just modify your user global environment variables so that every instance of cmd.exe will include it.

Comment: python is so much fun with that

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it done using this application  http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing `.py` extension from `file.py` name and then ran command `python file` python can understand the code without any extension for single file, but if you use modules then you need to use `.py` extension. Else you can add `.py` to path text in enviornment variables and run 
 
`assoc .py=Python.File` 
`ftype Python.File=c:\path to \python.exe "%1" %*`