# Run python programs without opening a separate shell

Tags: python, powershell

In powershell, when I run a python program with:

```
> python hello.py
```

The program runs and prints any output directly in the powershell window I'm working in.  But when I try to do it without explicitly invoking python:

```
> hello.py
```

it opens up a separate window.  How can I fix that so it behaves the same way it does when I invoke python explicitly?

Comment: Powershell is working as if you double clicked a file in a folder. Is is much trouble to write "python" ?

Comment: @JBernardo: No, it's not much trouble to type it.  But that's beside the point.  I'm working on setting up my environment in such a way that I can have programs/scripts written in any of a variety of languages and I can just execute them without knowing what language they are written in.  This is one of the steps in that goal.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows do not support hash bangs as other do. But it isn't any hard to open a file and check the first line for something like `#!python` and use the proper interpreter. Maybe you can even do it by the `.py` extension

Comment: You may need to change the default application for .py files to python.exe instead of whatever it is… but that may prevent double-clicking from opening a cmd window. Is that a reasonable tradeoff for you?

Comment: @abarnert: The default application for .py files *is* python.exe

Comment: OK, then there must be something else you need to change. (That's why I wrote a comment rather than an answer…) Anyway, the point is, if typing "hello.py" into Powershell does the same thing as double-clicking "hello.py" in Explorer, then it's pretty likely that whatever the fix is will also affect double-clicking files. Is that a reasonable tradeoff, or not?

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, that's fine.

Comment: I think you probably have a the `.py` extension associated with pythonw.exe. Change to be associated with python.exe.

Comment: @Keith: [Nope](http://postimage.org/image/mg2k1oa2j/)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley well, next suggestion: use Linux. ;-)

Comment: @Keith: I tried that too, for about a year and a half.  It has a host of other problems that I got sick of dealing with.

Comment: @JBernardo: [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher) adds shebang support. It installs with Python 3.3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you add `.PY` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you should be able to run `.\hello.py` or just `.\hello` in the current console. Otherwise it will `ShellExecute` the associated `Python.File` command (check `ftype Python.File`), which launches a new console.  I checked this by temporarily modifying the environment variable:

```
$env:pathext = $env:pathext + ";.PY"
```

Comment: Thanks.  That answered my next question too, which was about how I could get it to execute python programs without typing the extension.

Comment: Your next question has already been answered in [Making Python scripts run on Windows without specifying “.py” extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9037346/95735). I'm pretty sure this question has already been answered too.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: [You're right](http://superuser.com/q/437790/33682); I should have searched Stack Exchange before answering. To be clear, however, it doesn't open a `CMD` window as that question states. `python.exe` has an attached console. If it runs in a new window, you get a new console, but not a new `cmd.exe` shell.