# sys.argv Contents When Calling Python Script Implicitly on Windows

Tags: python, windows-7

I have a added `.PY` files to my System Environment `PATHEXT` variable on Windows 7. I have also added `C:\scripts` to my `PATH` variable.

Consider I have a very simple Python file C:\Scripts\helloscript.py

```
print "hello"
```

Now I can call Python scripts from my Console using:

```
C:\>helloscript
```

And the output is:

```
hello
```

If I change the script to be more dynamic, say take a first name as a second parameter on the Console and print it out along with the salutation:

```
import sys
print "hello,", sys.argv[1]
```

The output is:

```
c:\>helloscript brian
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Scripts\helloscript.py", line 2, in <module>
    print sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`sys.argv` looks like:

```
['C:\\Scripts\\helloscript.py']
```

---

If I call the script explicitly the way I would normally:

```
C:\>python C:\Scripts\helloscript.py brian
```

The output is:

```
hello, brian
```

If I try to use `optparse` the result is similar although I can avoid getting an error:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--firstname", action="store", type="string", dest="firstname")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
print "hello,", options.firstname
```

The output is:

```
hello, None
```

Again, the script works fine if I call it explicitly.

---

Here's the question. What's going on? Why doesn't `sys.argv` get populated with more than just the script name when calling my script implicitly?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037618/8747) indicates that there are more steps than you described. If you ran `ftype`, precisely what command line did you enter?

Comment: Tried that. It didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I had to manually edit the registry:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command was:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1"
```

And should have been:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```