# Impossible to set python.exe to *.py scripts on Win7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

i've installed py 2.7 (64bit) on my PC with Win7 (64bit) without problem but I'm not able to run *.py scripts via DOS shell without declare python full path.
Let me better explain :

If I type D:\ myscript.py it doesn't work. The script is open with wordpad 
If I type D:\ C:\Python27 myscript.py it works and run correctly

I try to change the default application software for *.py file via Win7 GUI ( control pannel etc etc) but without success.
Python is not present in the list of available sw and in any case also with the manual set I'm not able to associate python.exe at *.py files.

I've checked in my environment variables but I've not  found problem (python path  is declared in Path = C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts).

I've tried also to modify HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT->Applications->python.exe->shell->open->command :
old register  value "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1"
new register  value "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

without success.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Does "python myscript.py" work for you?

Comment: Did you install for all users? If so, fix this in an elevated command prompt (i.e. run cmd.exe as administrator.... FYI, cmd is a shell, not an operating system or emulator, and certainly not DOS; it's a Windows console program). Run `assoc .py=Python.File` and `ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: Also run `assoc .pyw=Python.NoConFile` and `ftype Python.NoConFile="C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another check to make, which helped me figure out what was going on.

I switched from the 32bit Anaconda to the 64bit version. I deinstalled, downloaded then reinstalled, but several things didn't get cleaned up properly (quick launch stuff, and some registry keys). The problem on my side was that the default installation path changed, from `C:\Anaconda` to `C:\Anaconda2`.

I first tried the `assoc` and `ftype` tricks, everything was fine there. However, the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command` registry key was pointing to the old Anaconda path. As soon as I fixed this, `python.exe` showed up when I tried associating with "Open with" and everything went back to normal.

I also added the `%*` at the end in the registry key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `ASSOCIATE` command in CMD:

```
ASSOCIATE .py C:\PathTo\python.exe
```

More information at http://ss64.com/nt/associate.html

Answer (score 0):

@slv 's answer is good and helped me a bit with solving this problem. Anyhow, since I had previous installations of Python before this error occured for me, I might have to add something to this. One of the main problems hereby was that the directory of my python-installation changed.

So, I opened `regedit.exe` and followed these to steps:

1. I searched the entire registry for `.py`, `.pyw`, `.pyx` and `.pyc` (hopefully I did not forget to mention any here). Then, I radically deleted all occurrences I could find.
2. I searched the entire registry for my *old* python-installation-path (e.g. `C:\Users\Desktop\Anaconda3`). Then I replaced this path with my new installation path (e.g. `C:\Users\Desktop\Miniconda3`). Thereby, I also came across and replaced `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command` which @slv mentioned.

Afterwards, it was possible again to connect a `.py`-file from the `Open with...`-menu with my `python.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

The *.py file is a source code file. If you set up your system environment correctly, you need to run  python myscript.py

the following answer is related to your question
[Making Python scripts run on Windows without specifying ".py" extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037346/making-python-scripts-run-on-windows-without-specifying-py-extension?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Do you know that when you change the default application of a file, you are able to browse for the application?

You can click on the "browse" button (as shown in the red rectangle), then choose C:\Python27\python.exe.

Also remember to click on the "Always use this program to open this program" checkbox, which is shown in the green rectangle, so that win7 knows how to open this file the next time you ask it to open *.py file.

Then I believe you'll be able to run myScript.py simply by typing "myScript.py" in the correct dirctory in DOS shell.

[image]

After doing all the above steps, be sure to reopen a new command shell.

Comment: Hi Lyen,I tried via Win7 GUI (as you show above) but although I see the application listed the set operation doesn't work and I can not associate *.py file to python.exe

Comment: Did you click on the "Always use this program to open this program" checkbox ?

Comment: Yes...I've done it., but "Win" ignores my wishes,this is the reason because I asked here alternative way or workaround.